# My aim in the study is to generate random colors and apply them to the body background, but it doesn't work, why is it wrong?

Tags: javascript, function, dom, addeventlistener

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRxIh.png)

what is the problem here function or addeventlistener?

`

```
const button = document.querySelector("button");

// Generate random color value and return it. EX 8a6cff
const getRandomColor = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xffffff).toString(16);

const generateGradient = () => {
// Get random two colors for gradient
const color1 = getRandomColor();
const color2 = getRandomColor();

// Apply the gradient to the body background
document.body.style.background = 'linear-gradient(to left top, #${color1},   #${color2})';
}
generateGradient();

button.addEventListener("click", generateGradient);
```

`

Comment: u are using wrong quotes, should be backticks like so: `linear-gradient(to left top, #${color1},   #${color2})`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is mistake in block where you try to apply the gradient to the body background

You should replace (') quotes by  backtick characters (`) in line where you use variables in string

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<button id='color'>
COLOR
</button>
<script>
// Generate random color value and return it. EX 8a6cff
const getRandomColor = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xffffff).toString(16);

const generateGradient = () => {
// Get random two colors for gradient
const color1 = getRandomColor();
const color2 = getRandomColor();

// Apply the gradient to the body background
document.body.style.background = `linear-gradient(to left top, #${color1},   #${color2})`;
}
generateGradient();

button = document.getElementById('color');
button.addEventListener("click", generateGradient);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
document.body.style.background = `linear-gradient(to left top, #${color1},   #${color2})`;
```